# Xamarin - how to read text from the "application log"

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios, xamarin.android

I'm using third party library (Android/iOS native libraries with C# bindings) which is logging their output "somehow" and I can see it in the Debug Console while debugging my application.

Is there any way to read those logs programmatically from C# code?
I'm not even sure where those logs are coming from.

I have tried custom Trace/Debug listeners - nothing is logged there except my own Debug/Trace calls.

Comment: please add some actual code to your question.